# How to add a new column to pandas from 2 lists based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [1,2,3], 'col_b':[2,3,4]})
```

I also 4 lists:

```
index_list_a = [0,2]
value_list_a = ['a', 'c']

index_list_b = [1]
value_list_b = ['b']
```

I would like to add a new column in `df` where it will take the value from either `value_list_a` or `value_list_b` depending if the index is in `index_list_a` or `index_list_b`

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
df[df.index.isin(index_list_a)]['col_f'] = value_list_a
df[df.index.isin(index_list_b)]['col_f'] = value_list_b
```

Comment: What would be the output? Mind that the index starts at 0.

Comment: @alec_djinn you were right, i edited that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
s =pd.Series(dict(zip(index_list_a+index_list_b,value_list_a+value_list_b)),name='colF')
#s=pd.Series(data=value_list_a+value_list_b,index=index_list_a+index_list_b,name='colF')
out = df.join(s)
```

---

```
   col_a  col_b colF
0      1      2    a
1      2      3    b
2      3      4    c
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but it is quite readable and easy to follow:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [1,2,3], 'col_b':[2,3,4]})

index_list_a = [0,2]
value_list_a = ['a', 'c']

index_list_b = [1]
value_list_b = ['b']


for index, value in zip(
    index_list_a + index_list_b,
    value_list_a + value_list_b
):
    df.loc[index, 'col_f'] = value
    
print(df)
   col_a  col_b col_f
0      1      2     a
1      2      3     b
2      3      4     c
```

The one-liner and more efficient version of this is (as pointed out by @Shubham Sharma):

```
df.loc[index_list_a + index_list_b, 'col_f'] =  value_list_a + value_list_b
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change the assigning part to use loc and put a placeholder for col_f

```py
df['col_f'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.index.isin(index_list_a),"col_f"] = value_list_a
```

Second I think you have mistake. Your code has index [1,3], but python starts at 0.

```py
index_list_a = [0,2]
value_list_a = ['a', 'c']
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [1,2,3], 'col_b':[2,3,4]})

index_list_a = [0,2]
value_list_a = ['a', 'c']

index_list_b = [2]
value_list_b = ['b']

df['col_f'] = np.nan


df.loc[df.index.isin(index_list_a),"col_f"] = value_list_a
```

But if you want a general solution and the [1,3] was intentional you can use the function below

```py
def create_intersect(x,y,z):
    common = list(set(x).intersection(set(y)))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] not in common:
            y.pop(i); z.pop(i);
    return y,z
```

This allows you to eliminate any index that doesn't exist in the data frame before hand

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def create_intersect(x,y,z):
    common = list(set(x).intersection(set(y)))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] not in common:
            y.pop(i); z.pop(i);
    return y,z



df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [1,2,3], 'col_b':[2,3,4]})

index_list_a,value_list_a = create_intersect(df.index, [1,3], ['a', 'c'])

df['col_f'] = np.nan

df.loc[df.index.isin(index_list_a),"col_f"] = value_list_a
```